# VSCode: Suppress all warnings from a particular Extension

Tags: vscode-extensions, visual-studio-code

I've got a code formatting extension, with format on save enabled. Unfortunately, it annoyingly gives me a warning every time I save but my program fails to parse. This information is redundant, since there are other packages which inform me of the error in a much less intrusive way.

Is there any way to block all notifications/warnings from a particular package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone coming across this in the future, it is possible as of VS Code 1.86 to disable notifications from a specific extension. Click the gear icon on the notification pop-up and there will be an option in the drop-down menu for making the extension stfu.

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible as of VS Code 1.18.

Please file an issue against the responsible extension so that they can fix this